# File manipulation through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have an Excel inside a Sharepoint which I'm perfectly able to read making a call to Graph API  from Python using msal library. I'm stuck in trying to update this file. I gave the application the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission and I can see it decoding the token through [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms):

```
{
    ...
    "roles": [
        "Files.ReadWrite.All"
    ]
    ...
}
```

These are the permissions of my application: [image: App permissions]

Despite this, when I try to send the `PATCH` http request to the file passing the structure to update I get a 403 AccessDenied error, it says that the operation can't be performed. It's not a problem of the structure I'm passing as it works fine in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). It seems a permissions problem but I don't know which other permission might be missing...

How can I find out where the problem is?

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I'm using:

client instance generation:

```
client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id
    ,authority = authority
    ,client_credential = client_secret
)
```

token request:

```
tk = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
```

the simple HTTP request:

```
requests.request(
    method = 'PATCH'
    ,headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tk['access_token']}
    ,url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{}/drive/items/{}/workbook/worksheets(\'{}\')/range(address=\'B2:C{}\')'.format(CONFIGS['app']['sharepoint_id'], CONFIGS['app']['workbook_id'], sheet, (CONFIGS['app']['nRows'] + 1))
    ,json = {...}
)
```

where `json` has a format like this (I'm emptying some cells):

```
{
    "values": [
        ["", ""]
    ],
    "formulas": [
        [null, null]
    ],
    "numberFormat": [
        [null, null]
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have set all readwrite permissions that exists on files API as you can see in this screenshot, still having a 403:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code how do you update the file?

Comment: @user2250152 updated the question with a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot of your permissions, it looks like you need delegated permission `Files.ReadWrite.All` instead of application.

I'm not sure about `PATCH`, according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-updating-an-existing-file), you should send `PUT` request to update a content of the file

### Update:

You are calling [workbook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and this API doesn't support application permissions.

Comment: I tried both delegated and application permissions, even together, with the same result. About `PATCH` request, it works fine from Graph Explorer, it is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Comment: Oh, and about delegated permission, if I set just that without application permission, I get a 403 with this message: "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.". That's why I set the application permission.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the update. You are calling Workbook API and it doesn't support [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) :(